# Handling Object with a key of unknown number

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Wikipedia's api and the response looks like this:

```
{
 'query': {
          'pages': {
                    212187: {
                             'extract': value;
                            }
                   }
          }
}
```

I am trying to get the extract value. However, when I cannot get past the 212187 because it is a number that will change with each call I make. This is not allowing me to accurately model out the response object. 
The current model I have is undefined at the 212187 level and blocking me from getting to extract.

How can I accomplish this? Any help/suggestions/tips would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I have an interface that matches the response structure exactly except the 212187 I have as number (assumed that would be wrong).
My Request looks like:

```
  fetchDescriptionWiki(qSearch: string) {
    const params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
      params.set('origin', '*');
      params.set('format', 'json');
      params.set('action', 'query');
      params.set('prop', 'extracts');
      params.set('exintro', '');
      params.set('explaintext', '');
      params.set('indexpageids', '');
      params.set('titles', qSearch);
    const options = new RequestOptions({
      search: params
    });
    return this.http.get(this.pendingCardsDescriptionWikiUrl, options)
      .map(this.extractApiData);
  }
```

extractApiData:

```
  private extractApiData(res: Response) {
    const body = res.json();
    return body || [];
  }
```

My component.ts function looks like:

```
getDescription() {
  this.pendingCardService.fetchDescriptionWiki('SomeStringValue')
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.wikiResult = data;
    });
}
```

This is where I got stuck with being able to dig into the response and get the value of extract.

Comment: You mean in terms of the *types*? You need something like `{ [key: number]: Extract }`.

Comment: Could you add some of the code you are currently using to work with this data structure?

Comment: Do you mind expanding your explanation @jonrsharpe? Do you mean in the interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used something along the following to retrieve the data from a Wikipedia API Extract Query using Angular HttpClient (Angular 4+). It utilizes [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) then targeting the desired page via array index (index 0 in this case) so you wouldn't need to know the page id.

I've updated the answer to use the class and method names from your example. I'd recommend to upgrade to `HttpClient`, but you'd be able to achieve the same result with Angular 2's `Http`.

```
@Injectable()
export class PendingCardService {

    private: string wikipediaUrl =
        'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query' +
        '&format=json&prop=extracts&exintro=1&explaintext=1' +
        '&origin=*&titles=Some_title';

    fetchDescriptionWiki(): Observable<any> {
        // this can use URLSearchParams as you did
        return this.http.get(this.wikipediaUrl).map(this.extractApiData);
    }

    private extractApiData(res: Response): Foobar {
       // json() is unnecessary in Angular 4+ as json() is automatically called
       const body = res.json();

       const pages = body.query.pages;
       const pageKeys = Object.keys(pages);

       // Retrieve the first page (index 0)
       const page = pages[pageKeys[0]];

       // ES6 object destructuring to get extract value
       const { extract } = page;

       // creating some object from retrieved value
       const foobar: Foobar = { extract };

       return foobar;
    }
}
```

Component:

```
getDescription() {
  this.pendingCardService.fetchDescriptionWiki()
    .subscribe((foobar: Foobar) => {
      this.wikiResult = foobar;
    });
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I didn't realize your were looking for the model definition rather than the process to extract the data, hopefully it still helps in some way. Thanks!

Comment: Honestly I am looking for both. Just trying to get to the extract value. I haven't updated to 4.3.4 yet so I haven't spent time with HttpClient. I will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Updated the answer to use the class/method names you provided. After calling json(), you should be able to access the `extract` property via `Object.keys()`. I'm using this approach (Angular 4+) to specifically get at the `extract` property when targeting a single/specific page title. You'd ideally access the values in the `extractApiData()` executed from `map()`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
interface IWikipediaData {
    query: {
        pages: {
            [key: number]: {
                extract: string
            }
        }
    }
}

let example: IWikipediaData = {
    query: {
        pages: {
            212187: {
                extract: 'value'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that DeborahK will need to know the page number to get the extract value. Would help to implement setter custom implementation an re-format the response in order to get a more dev firendly object.